# Can I open a seperate XML layout with a OnLongClick

Tags: java, android, xml

I am currently experimenting with layouts and opening new pages, I would like to open one page with a OnLongClickListener but a toast with a OnClickListener using the same text view box.

This is what I've designed so far. It won't work as the long click needs to output a boolean.
 Any Ideas?

XML main

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.how_to_use.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/main_view">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/long_press_textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Long Press To Open \n'Drag n Drop'"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

XML 2nd page

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/swirl_img"
    android:src="@drawable/Swirl"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.Java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private LinearLayout mainView;
  private TextView txtView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.long_press_textView);
    addListenerLongPressBtn();
    addListenerOnClickBtn();
}

public void addListenerOnClickBtn() {
    txtView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Press Secret Button for Longer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

    public void addListenerLongPressBtn() {

        txtView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, DragDropActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: There is more on the original but I've disregarded any non relative code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my own problem.

```
    public void addListenerLongPressBtn() {

        txtView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DragDropActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```